# Alternatives to RunAs for user context in test classes?

Tags: unit-test, sharing-rule

I need to run a test method in the context of a user because of a conditional default field being set based on parts of the users email address.

The problem: I only need the users email address in the context but not the sharing rules active as some sharing rules will never work as they are conditional in production on related record Ids.

Is there any way to get into a user context (email only) with other permissions and sharing disabled?

Example:

User 1: myemail@company1.com
User 2: anotherone@company2.com

"Using SOQL to get mail adress of current user."

runAs(User1)

insert Opportunity xy...
(with default_field = 987 set by trigger)

runAs(User2)

insert Opportunity xy
(with default_field= 1234 set by trigger)

runAs System again:

assert if correct defaults were set.

Comment: Can you share your current code? This sounds like a use case for mocking, either by mocking the insert DML (by not actually inserting a record into the database) or by abstracting the way a users email is retrieved from their User record. That is, having your class refer to `UserInfo` to get the User's email in practice but a mock method that returns a pre-determined email for testing.

Comment: Use a "fake user" - instantiate and insert the User in the test itself and use System.runAs with this "fake user". You have full control over how that user instance is configured so should be able to avoid such issues.

Comment: Hi @nbrown, could you elaborate on mocking the insert? How would this work?

To share my code I need to anonimize a lot of lines. Will do so next week if I can't solve the problem.

Comment: @PhilW interesting! could I also take an existing user and change his stats? like how would I do permission sets or roles? Can you provide examples?

Comment: @mlew instead of making DML statements directly in your test or in your class that you're testing, you would instead give the responsibility of interacting with the database to a data accessor object that has a concrete and a mock implementation and switch them based on whether or not you're testing. Look up the data access object pattern if you're interested. That said, Phil's suggestion of instantiating a fake user will be a quicker solution - without needing to change the implementation of your class. If you set `SeeAllData=true` in your test class you can query for permissions and roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have some predefined profiles (only used for testing purposes) and simply instantiate the User instance(s) we need in our tests:

```
List<Profile> profiles = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = :profileToMatch LIMIT 1];

if (profiles.isEmtpy()) {
    System.assert(false, 'Testing profile is missing');
}

Id profileId = profiles[0].Id;
User dummy = new User(FirstName = 'Frank', LastName = 'Lee',
        Alias = 'frankly',
        Email = 'frank.lee@dummy.com',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
        ProfileId = profileId,
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'Europe/London',
        Username = 'frank.lee@dummy.com');

insert dummy;

...

System.runAs(dummy) {
    ...
}
```

In terms of permissions, that can be done using profile or by adding permission sets to the user. You can't easily programmatically set these up (hence we have pre-defined ones for tests) - I think it is possible but you have to mess about with the metadata API from Apex (there is at least one open source set of classes for this available if you search).

For us, we mostly don't care about permissions when running unit tests; we never directly check permissions but instead indirect through our own security check class which is designed to allow us to turn off permission checks in unit tests (with selective enablement if we choose).

Comment: Hm I thought that this could solve it when I could assign a "see all Role". For permissions according to this Salesforce doc: "The runAs method doesn’t enforce user permissions or field-level permissions, only record sharing."
Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm?search_text=runAs

My problem is that I want to check for the correct role access behaviour as well in my unit test. As application updates are a pain if we don't have a test for that.

Will try a different approach. (Make change to sharing rule itself)

Comment: Ah, I see. I have no answer to that using OOTB functionality. As I mentioned, we indirect all permission checks so you could do the same and ensure it reflects the permissions you want it to reflect when it is used in Test.isRunningTest.

Comment: Okay I found something interesting though: Salesforce does not state that in full clarity:
Permissions that override sharing like "view all" and "modify all" in Profiles and in Permission sets do affect the runAs() context! That's especially useful to know as Salesforce does tell you about overriding profiles in the sharing rule screen, but not about overriding permission sets. 

That caused a lot of confusion for me. 

Finally I decided to seperate unit test and permission test to solve the problem. Thanks for the input.